# TSQL: Trigger / ROLLBACK TRANSACTION error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have trigger in TSQL that I would like to do two things:

1. If the "Locked" column is TRUE, it should ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
2. It should fail gracefully while doing so

   ```
   AFTER UPDATE 
   AS
   BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted WHERE Locked = 1)>0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END
   ```

Currently the code rolls back unwanted transactions, but when it does it returns this error: "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."

Is there a way to ROLLBACK TRANSACTION in the trigger and fail gracefully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could change to an INSTEAD OF trigger, and choose to perform or not perform the update, but its more code as you'd have to manually perform the update.

Comment: Hello Peter,

Thanks for the suggestion. Could you elaborate further on how I would perform or not perform the update?

I'm relatively new to SQL, so I appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, an after trigger is just called after the operation, an instead of trigger also has to perform the operation itself. This link may help: [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1804/using-instead-of-triggers-in-sql-server-for-dml-operations/).